# How do I create Bitmap from another image and keep the transparent background?

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I am trying to create a bitmap from a PNG image that has a transparent background. When I use this method below it makes the background black. I've tried using drawColor() with the color being transparent, but it is not working. Maybe I'm just overlooking something. So, my question is: How do I keep the transparency in a Bitmap? I am saving it as a PNG.

```
private Bitmap createCircularCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {      
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());         
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);        
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days. I found the solution just after posting this question. 
The problem was not in Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() The problem was in image.compress().
I was using the image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fos), But if I use image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos) then my problem is solved.

Comment: That's actually what I was using. I was never able to correct the issue. Like I said before, I think it was with using HTC's gallery app to crop. It would flatten the image layers...Because it would work fine with other. Of course, I haven't messed with this issue in quite some time. But it is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha channel is initially filled by 0xff. So you can try this

```
canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR))
```

Comment: I've messed around with this and still could not get it to work. However, if I create a bitmap with an image from a drawable resource, it works just fine. But not with an image from outside the apk such as an image retrieved from the device's image gallery. Thank you for your response, Stine.

Comment: After messing around some more, I think the problem is from the gallery's crop feature. It's losing the transparency when passing the data.